# SUM before JOIN in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum

I'm having a probably basic problem with an SQL query (I'm learning).

I'm tracking the vaccination status in the different Spanish regions.

Simplifying, I have two tables: one with the regions (ca) and their population, and the other with the region (ca), the day of each data (time) and the dosis administered.

In order to get the percentages of overall Spanish population vaccinated each day, I need to SUM all the populations of each region, and then divide the SUM of doses administered in all regions and then divide between that SUM.

However, when I do the JOIN, each population is added to every row, so the SUM is very high (it is counted once per time the region appears).

I think I need to SUM all the population before JOIN, but then, what column do I use to JOIN?

It is something like this:

````
SELECT
  time AS "time",
  SUM(SUM(v1.dose)) OVER (ORDER BY time)/'SP_population'
FROM vaccines v1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT SUM(population) AS 'SP_population' FROM ca_population) v2 ON ?????
GROUP BY time
ORDER BY time```

What should the ??? be?
````

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a `CROSS JOIN`.  You no longer care about regions so you want one population value for all rows:

```
SELECT v.time, p.sp_population, v.daily_dose,
       SUM(SUM(v.daily_dose)) OVER (ORDER BY time) / p.sp_population
FROM (SELECT v.time, SUM(v.dose) as daily_dose
      FROM vaccines v
      GROUP BY v.time
     ) v CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT SUM(population) as sp_population
      FROM ca_population
     ) p
ORDER BY time
```